# 401, Access is denied due to invalid credentials

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication, authorization

At global.aspx:

```
void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["MaintenanceMode"] == "true")
    if (!Request.IsLocal)
      if (Request.CurrentExecutionFilePathExtension == ".aspx")
        HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("Maintenance.htm");
}
```

At web.config:

```
<appSettings>  
  <add key="MaintenanceMode" value="true"/>  
</appSettings>
<location path="Maintenance.htm">  
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <allow users="*" />
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```

When running the web site locally via Visual Studio everything is fine,
but at the web server I'm getting a Username/Password login window,
which after pressing `Cancel` shows me the 401 message.
Also, entering the right Username and Password aren't accepted by the login window.
I'm using forms authentication.

Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: sound like a web server issue. Make sure the web site is configured correctly.

Comment: Any directions of what to look for?

Comment: I need to know a bit more about your environment: what server do you have and what version?

Comment: The site is hosted on a IIS 7, .NET 4, C#. When setting MaintenanceMode to false, the authentication works fine.

Comment: Are you sure that you don't have Windows authentication enabled for the site. If you do, then disabled it

Comment: All I have is this at config.web: `<authentication mode="Forms">
      <forms loginUrl="~/Account/Login.aspx" timeout="2880"/>
    </authentication>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the `Maintenance.htm` file to an `ASPX` format solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to note for anyone searching for this error that it can be caused by various errors in the web.config

This web.config is the essence of the web.config that solved the issue for me

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <security>
            <authentication>
                <anonymousAuthentication userName="" />
            </authentication>
        </security>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```